# 32 Bit excel VSTO add in Not working in 64 bit machine

Tags: excel, 64-bit, office365, vsto

I have VSTO project (excel addin) created in 32 bit machine and it was working fine. Recently we had to use 64 bit client machine to use same application, but when launching application, the content (drop down list,.. etc) of excel page become freeze. 
Any suggestion to resolve this issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe the architecture is the issue. If so, the plugin would not be loaded. You could check the DLLs linked to that plugin

Comment: is 32-bit Office installed on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: Yes. Both 32 and 64 bit versions of office are installed in the machine.

Comment: We were able to overcome this issue by doing 2 things. 

1. Upgrade interop dll into latest office.
2. Changes in settings
    Files -> options -> General Tab -> select radion button 'Optimize for Compatibility'

thanks all for helping.